# JavaScript Connect Four Game, Need help stopping the game after someone wins

Tags: javascript

This is a Connect Four Game that I am working on. The problem that if you click on the board after someone has won, then the score (number of wins) for that person keeps going up and it plays the "victory sound". How could I edit my code so that nothing happens if you click on the board after someone has won? It's for a project in school and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

```js
///////////////////// CONSTANTS /////////////////////////////////////
const winningConditions = [
//horizontal
  [35, 36, 37, 38],
  [36, 37, 38, 39],
  [37, 38, 39, 40],
  [38, 39, 40, 41],
  [28, 29, 30, 31],
  [29, 30, 31, 32],
  [30, 31, 32, 33],
  [31, 32, 33, 34],
  [21, 22, 23, 24],
  [22, 23, 24, 25],
  [23, 24, 25, 26],
  [24, 25, 26, 27],
  [14, 15, 16 ,17],
  [15, 16, 17, 18],
  [16, 17, 18, 19],
  [17, 18, 19, 20],
  [7, 8, 9 ,10],
  [8, 9, 10, 11],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [10, 11, 12, 13],
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 5, 6],
//vertical
  [35, 28, 21, 14],
  [28, 21, 14, 7],
  [21, 14, 7, 0],
  [36, 29, 22, 15],
  [29, 22, 15, 8],
  [22, 15, 8, 1],
  [37, 30, 23, 16],
  [30, 23, 16, 9],
  [23, 16, 9, 2],
  [38, 31, 24, 17],
  [31, 24, 17, 10],
  [24, 17, 10, 3],
  [39, 32, 25, 18],
  [32, 25, 18, 11],
  [25, 18, 11, 4],
  [40, 33, 26, 19],
  [33, 26, 19, 12],
  [26, 19, 12, 5],
  [41, 34, 27, 20],
  [34, 27, 20, 13],
  [27, 20, 13, 6],
//diagonal(right)
  [38, 32, 26, 20],
  [37, 31, 25, 19],
  [36, 30, 24, 18],
  [35, 29, 23, 17],
  [31, 25, 19, 13],
  [30, 24, 18, 12],
  [29, 23, 17, 11],
  [28, 22, 16, 15],
  [24, 18, 12, 6],
  [23, 17, 11, 5],
  [22, 16, 10, 4],
  [21, 15, 9, 2],
//diagonal(left)
  [41, 33, 25, 17],
  [40, 32, 24, 16],
  [39, 31, 23, 15],
  [38, 30, 22, 14],
  [34, 26, 18, 10],
  [33, 25, 27, 9],
  [32, 24, 26, 8],
  [31, 23, 25, 7],
  [27, 19, 11, 3],
  [26, 18, 10, 2],
  [25, 17, 9, 1],
  [24, 16, 8, 0]
];


///////////////////// APP STATE (VARIABLES) /////////////////////////
let board;
let turn;
let win;
let redWins = 0;
let yellowWins = 0;
let ties = 0;
let first;
let winner;
///////////////////// CACHED ELEMENT REFERENCES /////////////////////
const dots = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#board div"));
const message = document.querySelector("h2");
///////////////////// EVENT LISTENERS ///////////////////////////////
window.onload = init;
document.getElementById("board").onclick = takeTurn;
document.getElementById("reset-button").onclick = playAgain;
document.getElementById("redFirst").onclick = redFirst;
document.getElementById("yellowFirst").onclick = yellowFirst;
document.getElementById("reset-scoreboard").onclick = resetScoreboard;
///////////////////// FUNCTIONS /////////////////////////////////////

function init() {
  board = [
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  ];
  turn = "Red"
  win = null

  render();
}


function render() {
  board.forEach(function(mark, index) {
    dots[index].textContent = mark;
  });

  message.textContent =
    win === "T" ? "It's a tie!" : win ? `${win} wins!` : `Turn: ${turn}`;
}

function takeTurn(e) {

 if (e.target.id == "board") {
    return false;
  }

if (!win) {
let index = dots.findIndex(function(dot) {
  return dot === e.target;
});


let row1 = index % 7;

if (board[index] === "") {

  while (board[index + 7] === "") {
    let i = index + 7;
    document.getElementById("dot" + i + "").classList.add(turn);
    board[i] = turn;
    document.getElementById("dot" + index + "").classList.remove(turn);
    board[index] = "";
    index = i;

  }
  if (board[index] === "") {
    document.getElementById("dot" + index + "").classList.add(turn);
    board[index] = turn;

  }

  }
  else if (board[index] !== "") {
    if (board[row1] === "") {
      while (board[row1 + 7] === "") {
        let i = row1 + 7;
        document.getElementById("dot" + i + "").classList.add(turn);
        board[i] = turn;
        document.getElementById("dot" + row1 + "").classList.remove(turn);
        board[row1] = "";
        row1 = i;

      }
      if (board[row1] === "") {
        document.getElementById("dot" + row1 + "").classList.add(turn);
        board[row1] = turn;

      }

    }
    else if (board[row1] !== "") {
      return false;
    }
   }

  }

  turn = turn === "Red" ? "Yellow" : "Red";
  win = getWinner();
  if (win === "T") {
    ties++;
    document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
  }

  render();
}



function getWinner() {
  let winner = null;

  winningConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
    if (
      board[condition[0]] &&
      board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
      board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]] &&
      board[condition[2]] === board[condition[3]]
    ) {
      winner = board[condition[0]];
      if (winner === "Red") {
        redWins++;
        document.getElementById("redScore").innerHTML = redWins;
        playOKOK();

      }
      else if (winner === "Yellow") {
        yellowWins++;
        document.getElementById("yellowScore").innerHTML = yellowWins;
        playOKOK();

      }

    }

  });

  return winner ? winner : board.includes("") ? null : "T";
}

function playAgain() {
  board.forEach(function(mark, index) {
    if (dots[index].classList.contains("Red")) {
      dots[index].classList.remove("Red")
    }
    if (dots[index].classList.contains("Yellow")) {
      dots[index].classList.remove("Yellow")
    }
  });
  init()
}

function resetScoreboard() {
  redWins = 0;
  yellowWins = 0;
  ties = 0;

  document.getElementById("redScore").innerHTML = redWins;
  document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
  document.getElementById("yellowScore").innerHTML = yellowWins;
}

function redFirst(){
  init();
  playAgain();
  document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Turn: Red";
  turn = "Red";
  first = "Red"


}

function yellowFirst(){
  init();
  playAgain();
  document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Turn: Yellow";
  turn = "Yellow";
  first = "Yellow"

}

function resetScoreboard() {
    redWins = 0;
    yellowWins = 0;
    ties = 0;

    document.getElementById("redScore").innerHTML = redWins;
    document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    document.getElementById("yellowScore").innerHTML = yellowWins;
  }

function playOKOK() {
  document.getElementById("myAudio").play();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: periwinkle;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  border-color: black;
}

p {
  background-color: black;
}
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  text margin: 0px;
}

td {
  border-color: black;
}

p {
  background-color: black;
}
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dot {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none;

}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 750px;
  width: 750px;
}

.container {
align-items: center;
}

.containerv2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.columnv2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Red {
  background-color: red;
  color: transparent;
}

.Yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: transparent;
}

.first {
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 46px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 100px;
  user-select: none;
  width: 110px;
  margin: 5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.first:hover {
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}

.scoreboard {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 2%;
  border-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#board {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 123px;
  user-select: none;
}

#yellowFirst {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#redFirst {
  background-color: red;
}

#reset-button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 456px;

}

#reset-button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#turn {
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#reset-scoreboard {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 456px;
}

#reset-scoreboard:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Connect Four</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/connect4.css">
    <script defer src="js/connect4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio id="myAudio">
      <source src="audio/okok.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <ul>
      <li><a  href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a  href="tic-tac-toe.html">Tic-Tac-Toe</a></li>
      <li><a href="ultimate-tic-tac-toe.html">Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="connect4.html">Connect Four</a></li>
    </ul>

      <h1>Connect Four</h1>



        <h3>Who's going first?</h3>
        <div class="containerv2 columnv2">


        <div class="containerv2">
          <div class="first" id="redFirst"></div>
          <div class="first" id="yellowFirst"></div>
        </div>


        <table class="scoreboard">
          <tr>
            <td># of Red Wins:</td>
            <td># of Ties:</td>
            <td># Of Yellow Wins:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="redScore">0</td>
            <td id="tScore">0</td>
            <td id="yellowScore">0</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="reset-scoreboard">Reset Scoreboard</div>
      <h2 id="turn">Turn: Red</h2>
      </div>

     <div class="container column">
      <div class="wrap container" id="board">
        <div class="dot" id="dot0"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot1"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot2"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot3"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot4"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot5"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot6"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot7"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot8"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot9"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot10"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot11"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot12"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot13"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot14"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot15"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot16"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot17"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot18"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot19"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot20"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot21"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot22"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot23"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot24"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot25"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot26"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot27"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot28"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot29"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot30"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot31"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot32"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot33"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot34"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot35"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot36"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot37"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot38"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot39"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot40"></div>
        <div class="dot" id="dot41"></div>

      </div>

      <div id="reset-button">Play Again!</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already have your app state variables, why not add one that indicates whether the game is over and check it before processing the click?

Comment: 588 lines of code is not exactly a [MCVE]

Comment: I can't hold my tongue: A giant table of all possible winning states? That is a horrible implementation. At a bear minimum keep the implementation the same but generate the table programmatically!